# Integration of Python ML Model with a web application

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, machine-learning

Let us assume that, I have a Machine Learning model which uses the Tensorflow library and performs a function.

And of course, the function requires input and provides some output. Which can be easily done on my terminal.

Here comes the area where I need help, IO in the terminal is not what I wanted, I want to create a web application that has multiple functionalities. Let us only consider the area where my ML model has to work, say when I click a button after entering the inputs it runs the ML model back and provides me an output which I could display it on my web application.

I can develop websites with NodeJs. Is there any possibility of integrating the ML model with my web application made of NodeJs?

I tried running on some packages like **child-process,python-shell** nothing works, it gives me an error when it comes to the place of importing packages.

Please give me suggestions on the Integration of the ML model with a **NodeJS web application using MongoDB as a database**. All I wanted is that my web application runs my ML model wherever necessary to obtain the results which I can display through my web applications.

Also, provide information about technologies that can be easily integrated with the Machine learning model.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also encountering similar problems.

Further to the previous reply, I would go for the micro services architecture design.

E.g. Use a node.js app to serve the front-end request, and the Python server only to serve the machine learning tasks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to build a python web application around your model to serve responses (your model’s output) to the client (the webpage your nodejs app is serving).

Flask and Django are the major players there. REST is the most popular meta-framework.

Once you’ve built a REST API around your model, you just query it like any resource via HTTP/xmlhttprequest in JavaScript from your web page.

Or you can try to pickle your model and load into into JavaScript to query from your nodejs app.

Easier than either of those would be to use IBM Cloud Functions or AWS Lambda to expose your script/model. Very easy and cost effective.